# SQL Server 2000 - Can it perform bulk insert operations?

Tags: sql-server-2000, bulkinsert

Is it possible to perform a bulk insert with SQL Server 2000?

If so, please explain how. Third party tools/add-ons are not likely to be allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225968(v=sql.80).aspx